# Sheet with Google Script working on one account and not working on a different account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a Spreadsheet with some sheets inside. One with the name "Template".

Basically I am trying to do some basics operations and then make a copy of the resulted sheet. In my google account works fine. But in a different account "myFunction2()" is not working. The problem is on the line:

```
while (files.hasNext()) {
```

I do not know if is a problems of permissions. My account is a Gsuite account ... maybe a I have more rights to execute file operations ???

Here goes the code:

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var firstSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Template');
  var theSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Template');
  //check for the sheet with the same name
  if(theSheet != null){
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(theSheet);
  } else {
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(firstSheet);
    spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
    theSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of Template');
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(theSheet);
  }

  var fechaHoy = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  theSheet.getRange('G5').setValue(fechaHoy);
  theSheet.getRange('G5').setHorizontalAlignment("right");
}

function myFunction2() {
  var month = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "MM");
  var year = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy");
  var fileName = month + "_" + year;
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
  var i = 0;

  //check for file with the same name
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    i = i + 1;
    var file = files.next();
  }

  if (i == 0){
    //if file do not exist create in current folder
    var folders=DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Taxi");
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
      var folder = folders.next();
      var file = SpreadsheetApp.create(fileName);
      var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(file.getId());
      folder.addFile(copyFile);
      DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(copyFile);
    }
    //then open and make operations
    ops(fileName);
  } else {
    //if file exist open & make operations
    ops(fileName);
  }
}

function ops(fileName){
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);
  var spreadFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetFrom = spreadFrom.getSheetByName('Copy of Template');
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var spreadTo = SpreadsheetApp.open(files.next());

    //copy the copy_of_template to new sheet
    sheetFrom.copyTo(spreadTo);
    var sheetTo = spreadTo.getSheetByName("Copy of Copy of Template");

    //delete Sheet1 if exist
    var sheet1 = spreadTo.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    if(sheet1 != null){
      spreadTo.deleteSheet(sheet1);
    }

    //delete Hoja1 if exist
    var sheet11 = spreadTo.getSheetByName("Hoja1");
    if(sheet11 != null){
      spreadTo.deleteSheet(sheet11);
    }

    //change formulas for values
    //invoice number
    var cellFrom = sheetFrom.getRange("G4");
    var cellTo = sheetTo.getRange("G4");
    var x = cellFrom.getValue();
    cellTo.setValue(x);
    //cif cliente
    cellFrom = sheetFrom.getRange("F9");
    cellTo = sheetTo.getRange("F9");
    x = cellFrom.getValue();
    cellTo.setValue(x);
    //direccion cliente
    cellFrom = sheetFrom.getRange("F10");
    cellTo = sheetTo.getRange("F10");
    x = cellFrom.getValue();
    cellTo.setValue(x);
    //cp y poblacion cliente
    cellFrom = sheetFrom.getRange("F11");
    cellTo = sheetTo.getRange("F11");
    x = cellFrom.getValue();
    cellTo.setValue(x);
    //read IVA from Datos
    var sheetDatos = spreadFrom.getSheetByName('Datos');
    cellFrom = sheetDatos.getRange("B2");
    x = cellFrom.getValue();
    var iva = x;
    //change formulas inserting iva instead of old sheet reference
    for(var i = 19; i < 44; i++){
      cellTo = sheetTo.getRange('H' + i);
      var newF = '=if(' + iva+ '*G' + i + '>0, ' + iva + '*G' + i + ', "")';
      cellTo.setFormula(newF);
    }

    //change name of the copied sheet
    var cell1 = sheetFrom.getRange("G4");
    var y = cell1.getValue();
    y = Utilities.formatString('%06d', y);
    sheetTo.setName(y);


    //delete copy_of_template
    spreadFrom.deleteSheet(sheetFrom);

    //increment invoice number from number sheet
    var sheetNumber = spreadFrom.getSheetByName('Numero');
    var cell2 = sheetNumber.getRange("B1");
    var z = cell2.getValue();
    z = z + 1;
    cell2.setValue(z);

    //message ok & finish
    var theSheet = spreadFrom.getSheetByName('Template');
    spreadFrom.setActiveSheet(theSheet);
    Browser.msgBox('Factura guardada con exito. La puedes ver en la carpeta Facturas, el fichero con el nombre de: ' + fileName + ', la hoja numero: ' + y + '.');
  }
}


// Add a custom menu to the active spreadsheet, including a separator and a sub-menu.
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('FACTURA')
      .addItem('Paso 1 - Crear', 'myFunction1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Paso 2 - Guardar', 'myFunction2')
      .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: "The problem is on the line: while (files.hasNext()) {"   Would you please edit your question to include a copy of the Execution transcript?

Comment: Can you please provide the message error you're getting? About the permissions, maybe you don't own the "Taxi" folder or the folder doesn't exists and is returning null for the "folder" variable.

Comment: @AndresDuarte The error occurs well before "Taxi". It is likely at `var files=DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName);` and either the file doesn't exist or, as you suggested, there is a permission error.

Comment: @Tedinoz sorry, i confused `files.hasNext()` with `folders.hasNext()`. @Marius Danciu Then the permission problem could be that you don't own all the files with that file name in your Drive.

Comment: I found the error. When I copied the sheet to the new account, the folder "Taxi" wasnt created so the script give me an error. After I create the folder the script was still giving error. I guess is about the cache or something. Tried on a diferent computer and worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Good news. But still a concern that it didn't run on the first PC; I would like to suggest that you persevere with that PC, clear the cache, etc. There is something "not right"; perhaps the login, perhaps javascript is blocked, but the PC itself should make zero difference because the code is executed on the net.